# Google Play Release to Production for Closed track

Tags: android, google-play, production

I want to submit my Android app to Google Play, but I want to use the Closed track before I release the app into production. So I configured the email list for testers, hit the Review and Rollout buttons (everything in Closed track section), then a new button appeared "Release to Production". Does this mean Production for everybody, or just for my testers? And how are they going to access the app?

This is my first time submitting an app, and I am a little confused.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Clicking the "Release to production" from a Closed Track release doesn't make the app available to everybody. The app will be only available to the list of your testers.

I know this wording from Google is a little confusing. Before it go to Production (Public Access), it moves from alpha -> Beta -> Production and you can track these releases.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Now it says "Your app will become available to all users of the Play Store. Do you want to continue?" Is this how it's supposed to be? I want it to be available only to my testers, and I gave their email list. Are they going to get an email, or how does this work?